# recalculate field from datagridview

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, timespan

I have a datagridview in a windows form based on the following query :

```
select dbo.doss.behdr, dbo.doss.dosno, SUM(dbo.kbpres.uur) as SomUur, SUM(dbo.kbpres.minuut) as SomMinuut 
FROM dbo.kbpres INNER JOIN dbo.doss ON dbo.kbpres.ino = dbo.doss.ino 
WHERE (dbo.doss.behdr LIKE @cboBeheerder) 
GROUP BY dbo.doss.behdr, dbo.doss.dosno
```

Now, the fields uur and minuut are just integers. So it might happen uur=4 and minuut=140. Now I would like to have this in a extra column that it says 6:20:00 which is 4hours plus 140minutes (2hours 20minutes).

Can I do that in the sql query or how can I do that programmaticaly??

Comment: And how is the quesry processed? DataTable, LINQ?

Comment: in a dataset.xsd file and then when Iclick on a button through : this.kTableAdapter1.Fill(this.kDataSet.kbpres, cboBeheerder.Text);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line conversion for multiple rows returned...

(I typed this freehand, so you may need to do some syntax updates)

```
select 
   dbo.doss.behdr
,  dbo.doss.dosno
,  SUM(dbo.kbpres.uur) as SomUur
,  SUM(dbo.kbpres.minuut) as SomMinuut 
,  CAST ((SUM(dbo.kbpres.uur) + SUM(dbo.kbpres.minuut) / 60) AS Varchar(2)) + -- derives hour
   ':' + -- adds the ':'
   CAST ((SUM(dbo.kbpres.minuut) % 60) AS Varchar(2)) as [derivedColumn] -- derives the minutes

FROM 
   dbo.kbpres 
   INNER JOIN 
   dbo.doss ON dbo.kbpres.ino = dbo.doss.ino 

WHERE 
   (dbo.doss.behdr LIKE @cboBeheerder) 

GROUP BY 
   dbo.doss.behdr, dbo.doss.dosno
```

Comment: For oracle, replace + with || and you will need to use MOD() instead of %

Comment: Ray K , I'm sorry, but what if the result is like 26:10 which is actually 1day 2 hours 10 minutes, how can I catch that ??

Comment: You'd have to go up one more level, unfortunately, the line goes pretty long:


CAST(((SUM(dbo.kbpres.uur) + SUM(dbo.kbpres.minuut) / 60) % 24) AS Varchar(2) +
':'+
CAST(((SUM(dbo.kbpres.uur) + SUM(dbo.kbpres.minuut) / 60) / 24) AS Varchar(2) +
':' +
CAST ((SUM(dbo.kbpres.minuut) % 60) AS Varchar(2)) as [derivedColumn]


(again, please check syntax) but you are doing a mod 24 for day, divide by 24 for hour and mod 60 for minute.

Comment: Last problem for you -- what if its a single minute/hour? (i.e. 1:12:1) you'll have to check length and add a '0' in front.  You may want to do this in a function and call the function in line to prevent the SELECT statement from looking atrocious!

Answer (score 1):

You can get this value in this fashion,

```
SELECT (4*60 + 140) / 60 as hours,  (4*60 + 140) % 60 as minutes
```

You can choose to append it and display as Text, or Process this as a property via code since you would have the other fields defined.

Comment: the 4 and 140 are just examples, I have like 60000 rows in the table for just one behdr

Comment: replace 4 and 140 by the respective columns

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the uur and minuut values in a variable.Then get it formulated.

```
declare @hr int
declare @mint int
set @hr = SUM(dbo.kbpres.uur)
set @mint  = SUM(dbo.kbpres.minuut)

SELECT (@hr*60 + @mint) / 60 as hours,  (@hr*60 + @mint) % 60 as minutes
```

I think this will solve the prob please check

Comment: The declare sql construct or statement is not supported it says then ?

Comment: what is different ? I cannot use the 'declare' and 'set' in a query in the xsd wizard.

Comment: Sorry Nick,i told that in SQL query. I  don't have an idea in xsd wizard.